# RRDTool archives storing only NaN

Tags: raspberry-pi2, rrdtool, iot, rrd

I have a RRDB on raspberry Pi. The rrdb was created using

```
//RRA1: Archive point is saved every 5min, archive is kept for 1hour back. 
//RRA2-4: Archive point is saved every 1hour, archive is kept for 30day back.
//RRA5: Archive point is saved every 3hour, archive is kept for 1year back.
//RRA6-8: Archive point is saved every 1day, archive is kept for 5year back. 

 rrdtool create %s%s \
--step '300' \
--start '1438387200' \
'DS:temp:GAUGE:600:0:100' \
'DS:humidity:GAUGE:600:10:100' \
'DS:dewpoint:GAUGE:600:-60:100' \
'RRA:LAST:0.5:1:1' \
'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:12' \
'RRA:MIN:0.5:12:720' \
'RRA:MAX:0.5:12:720' \
'RRA:MIN:0.5:12:720' \
'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:36:2920' \
'RRA:MIN:0.5:288:1825' \
'RRA:MAX:0.5:288:1825' \
'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:288:1825'
```

The rrdb gets updated every 5 minutes, by a [c program](https://github.com/AdysTech/raspy-weather), triggered by cronjob.

```
rrdtool updatev dht11.rrd 1439622104:27.000000:44.000000:13.692617
```

The rrdb is getting its last values set as verified by

```
rrdtool lastupdate dht11.rrd
 temp humidity dewpoint

1439622104: 27.000000 44.000000 13.692617
```

But none of the RRA (archives) are getting updated. All of them still have NaN.

```
 rrdtool xport -s now-1h -e now DEF:a=/dht11.rrd:temp:AVERAGE XPORT:a:"Livingroom"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xport>
  <meta>
    <start>1439619000</start>
    <step>300</step>
    <end>1439619000</end>
    <rows>13</rows>
    <columns>1</columns>
    <legend>
      <entry>Livingroom</entry>
    </legend>
  </meta>
  <data>
    <row><t>1439619000</t><v>NaN</v></row>
    <row><t>1439619300</t><v>NaN</v></row>
    <row><t>1439619600</t><v>NaN</v></row>
    <row><t>1439619900</t><v>NaN</v></row>
    <row><t>1439620200</t><v>NaN</v></row>
    <row><t>1439620500</t><v>NaN</v></row>
    <row><t>1439620800</t><v>NaN</v></row>
    <row><t>1439621100</t><v>NaN</v></row>
    <row><t>1439621400</t><v>NaN</v></row>
    <row><t>1439621700</t><v>NaN</v></row>
    <row><t>1439622000</t><v>NaN</v></row>
    <row><t>1439622300</t><v>NaN</v></row>
    <row><t>1439622600</t><v>NaN</v></row>
  </data>
</xport>
```

Any idea as what I am doing wrong, and any tips on getting RRAs updated?

Comment: make sure you are using 1.5.4 for your tests ...